# How to secure webapp reachable by other app?

Tags: python, authentication

Scenario is that my webapp gets data
and clients app is fetching them.
Its server to server communication.

Are there any python examples or packages
that will secure my app from unverified request?

I looked at 'nonce'.Is it over kill?
If not are there examples how i could implement
it in python.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly your problem you could use Django, a framework for developing web application that naturally supports authentication upon web requests. For example, if you want to grant access to a view on your server to authenticated users you can just use decorators to secure it.

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def my_view(request):
...
```